# Application Name in toolbar hide when 5 item added in it , how to show app name always in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have added 5 items on `toolbar` and when I reviewed in medium and small phones then application name is not visible.

How can I set application name to show always and reduce toolbar's items size according to available devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by toolbar you are referring to the app's ActionBar, then what you are looking for is an overflow menu (that three vertical dots option you see on the top right corner of apps). Reading Android's docs on [menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) might help.

Basically you want to make sure some, or all of your items have the `android:showAsAction` property set to `never` or `ifRoom` as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action1_string"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action2_string"/>
</menu>
```

The key here is the `android:showAsAction` property, which allows you to specify when should an item be added to the bar and when it should be added to the overflow menu. Possible values are:

- `ifRoom`: Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it. If there is not room for all the items marked "ifRoom", the items with the lowest orderInCategory values are displayed as actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.
- `withText`: Also include the title text (defined by android:title) with the action item. You can include this value along with one of the others as a flag set, by separating them with a pipe |. E.g. : `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`
- `always`: Always place this item in the app bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action bar. Setting multiple items to always appear as action items can result in them overlapping with other UI in the app bar.
- `never`: Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.
- `collapseActionView`: The action view associated with this action item is collapsible. API 14 onwards.

[Source.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)